# h:selectOneListbox doesn't set value

Tags: jsf, selectonelistbox

I was trying to set enum gender from selectOneListbox, but it failed for some reason, so I tried with plain String and it still doesn't work. InputText works perfectly fine for instance. Here's the code xhtml:

```
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

            <h:outputLabel value="Name"/>         
            <h:inputText value="#{userProfileBean.name}"/>

            <h:outputLabel value="Name from list"/>
            <h:selectOneListbox value="#{userProfileBean.name}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Bob" itemLabel="bobLabel"/>
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="Cindy" itemLabel="cindyLabel"/>
            </h:selectOneListbox>

            <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{userProfileBean.saveChanges()}"/>

        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

and backend bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class UserProfileBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private UserDatabase userDB;

private User user;
private String name;

...getters/setters...

public void saveChanges() {
    user.setName(name);
}
```

does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: Is this the working code or the not working code? You shouldn't use `@ManagedBean` and `@Named` at the same time. The CDI pair is: `import javax.inject.Named` and `import javax.faces.view.ViewScoped`

Comment: It's the not working code. I removed @ManagedBean annotation, but it didn't fix the problem. Also imports seem to be fine...

Comment: Hmm, in this code, the setter `userProfileBean.setName(x)` will be called twice. Maybe, allways the second one sets null? Did you set a breakpoint at `userProfileBean.setName(x)`?

Comment: Hm what exactly do you mean by breakpoint?